# Is there a way to turn on center lines that snap image into center?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

my buddy has photoshop on a pc and when moving an image and it gets close to center these pink center lines appear and almost snaps the image perfectly into center? cannot figure out how or where to do this.

Answer (score 0):

View menu > Show > Smart Guides

[image]